# How to configure Cypress component testing when Cypress is installed outside the Frontend project

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner, angular-e2e

I have a Front-end App for that I am using cypress e2e testing.

The structure of this is : a folder with the (Angular) FE app; and outside this, another folder with the cypress installation. In my env file I set the deployed version app on which I am executing my e2e tests against (not localhost).

I've tried to install the cypress component testing libraries but those seem not to have access to the FE app files since the cypress folder install is placed outside of the FE app one. Is there any possibility to tweak this somehow?

(Note that I cannot change the installation cypress folder to be inside the FE app)

I've tried the installation from here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/angular/overview

The error I am having is:

> `import {mount} from 'cypress/angular' (cypress/angular not accessible)`

I am using cypress 10.11.0
Node -v: 18.14.1

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding another relative path to the `specPattern` configuration.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer: {
      framework: 'angular',
      bundler: 'webpack',
    },
    specPattern: ['**/*.cy.ts', '../MyAngularApp/**/*.cy.ts'],
  },
})
```

This should allow you to search outside the Cypress folder for tests.